# Possible to specify boot partition size during the installation?

Tags: partitioning, system-installation

I would like to install Ubuntu 14 as the only OS on my laptop. I will be installing from a USB stick. Learning from my recent experience, I would like to specify a boot partition size much larger than the default (which is about 250MB, leading to problems with system updates).

Is it possible to specify boot partition size during the installation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can choose the "something else" option and set up your partitions just the way you like, but it is best to simply not have a boot partition at all.  This is normally the default, unless you enable full disk encryption, then you have to have one.

Comment: You're right, I don't need a boot partition. It seems that it was automatically created because I checked LVM option during the installation.

Comment: @user1566515, ahh, right.. not sure why it does that.. you don't need one to use LVM.